# Redirecting passed arguments to a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, arguments

I would like to call a jar file from a windows batch file. One requirement is to be able to pass all the batch file arguments as-is to the jar file invocation. For example,

Required Command line:

```
foo.bat --flag1=x --flag2=y --flag3=z
```

The batch file `foo.bat` should invoke `foo.jar` like follows:

```
java -jar foo.jar --flag1=x --flag2=y --flag3=z
```

**How do I make the batch file do this?** 
I can do some batch variable magic with % to do this, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Does

```
java -jar foo.jar %*
```

meet your needs?  It should add all parameters from the batch execution to your application call within the batch file.

Comment: This does not preserve the quotations. :'(

Comment: I think I found a solution that works with parameters in quotations: https://serverfault.com/a/22541

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Windows 10 1903, including preserving double-quotes around arguments.

Comment: @Sam "This" being the original answer, or Speedstone's link?

Comment: @Erhannis For me, it is the original answer. It kept the quotation marks where they belonged. :)