# Getting only response header from HTTP POST using cURL

Tags: post, curl, http-headers

One can request only the headers using HTTP HEAD, as option `-I` in `curl(1)`.

```
$ curl -I /
```

Lengthy HTML response bodies are a pain to get in command-line, so I'd like to get only the header as feedback for my POST requests. However, HEAD and POST are two different methods.

How do I get cURL to display only response headers to a POST request?

Answer (score 938):

```
-D, --dump-header <file>
       Write the protocol headers to the specified file.

       This  option  is handy to use when you want to store the headers
       that a HTTP site sends to you. Cookies from  the  headers  could
       then  be  read  in  a  second  curl  invocation by using the -b,
       --cookie option! The -c, --cookie-jar option is however a better
       way to store cookies.
```

and

```
-S, --show-error
       When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it fails.
```

from the man page.  so

```
curl -sS -D - www.acooke.org -o /dev/null
```

follows redirects, dumps the headers to stdout and sends the data to /dev/null (that's a GET, not a POST, but you can do the same thing with a POST - just add whatever option you're already using for POSTing data)

note the `-` after the `-D` which indicates that the output "file" is stdout.

Comment: above comment is valid if you're using powershell. for cmd.exe use `curl -s -D - http://yahoo.com -o nul`

Comment: @JJS for me $null worked on Win7. Is it due to cLink installed on windows.

Comment: The "-" in front of the URL may seem unimportant, but it's not.

Comment: @WahidSadik Why's is that the case in particular? What's the function of the single dash?

Comment: @mamachanko `-D` takes an argument that says where the output should go.  the single dash means it should go to stdout.

Comment: Man I'm never gonna remember all that. I guess I need to make an alias for this one since I frequently want to do this.  :\

Comment: Dropping the -o /dev/null will get your entire response body PLUS header. Also useful IMO.

Comment: Nice answer, I wrapped that in a bash function: https://github.com/tlehman/bin/blob/master/headers

Comment: Or as helper function in bash `function headers {curl -s -D - $1 -o /dev/null}`.

Comment: If you get empty output and you're targeting HTTPS, then you either need to provide a cert (`--cacert`), or use `--insecure` flag

Comment: @SatyaPrakash For me, `$null` writes to a file when cLink is installed.

Comment: I'd add `-L` to follow redirects

Comment: If for some reason you literally just want the headers and not the HTTP status code line (`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`), you can pipe it to `tail`: ` | tail -n +2`

Comment: This still prints response body with MINGW

Answer (score 279):

The other answers require the response body to be downloaded. But there's a way to make a POST request that will only fetch the header:

```
curl -s -I -X POST http://www.google.com
```

An `-I` by itself performs a HEAD request which can be overridden by `-X POST` to perform a POST (or any other) request and still only get the header data.

Comment: This answer is actually correct because web servers can return different headers based on request method. If you want to check headers on GET, you have to use GET request.

Comment: This is the most correct answer, in my opinion. It is easy to remember, it actually sends `GET` request and doesn't download the whole response body (or at least doesn't output it). The `-s` flag is nor necessary.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII well kinda nitpicking I would say. You can replace `GET` with `POST` in above command and it will work as expected. `or any other` is key there.

Comment: This does not work when you actually want to `POST` some data. Curl says: `Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).`

Comment: The answer below is better, using `-X HEAD`, which won't download the whole file. This is useful if you want to see how large a zip is before fetching it from a server. `curl -s -I -X HEAD https://path/to/some/large.zip` for example.

Comment: @nickboldt The point here is that a server might respond differently to a HEAD request than to a POST or GET request (and some servers actually do that), so `-X HEAD` is no reliable solution here.

Comment: Very useful tips.

Comment: I get `Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST 
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).`

Comment: @Stewart read the other comments first please.
By the by, `-s` does become useful once you pipe the output, for example to `grep`.

Comment: @xeruf  I got the same error as @SebastianH above.  Nothing to do with `-s`

Answer (score 109):

The Following command displays extra informations

```
curl -X POST http://httpbin.org/post -v > /dev/null
```

You can ask server to send just HEAD, instead of full response

```
curl -X HEAD -I http://httpbin.org/
```

`Note:` In some cases, server may send different headers for POST and HEAD. But in almost all cases headers are same.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the other answer won, because this is the correct answer - it doesn't unnecessarily transfer a ton of data.

Comment: @dmd If I understand the cURL manual for [`-X, --request`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X) correctly, `-X HEAD` still results in “a ton of data” but there is [`-I, --head`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-I) which should results in what you are anticipating.

Comment: You do not understand it correctly.  `-X HEAD` and `-I` are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Problem with `-X HEAD` is that the server might respond differently, since it now receives a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` (or whatever the previous request was)

Comment: `Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.`

Comment: Why does this have a ton of upvotes? The question is "how to only get the headers when making a POST request", not "how to make a HEAD request".

Comment: @bfontaine The answer shows both POST and HEAD and since you can't get away with body from POST request it shows how to redirect it to NUL device. So author recommends to still use HEAD because the question was about how to avoid lengthy body.

Comment: @zainengineer `-vvv` - is that super-extra verbose? (can't find anything in docs)

Comment: @FrankNocke yes its super extra verbose, although it can just work with -v

Comment: @bfontaine a perfect example of a [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Grav, this is an interesting proviso because by the RFC, "HTTP headers in response to a `HEAD` request *SHOULD* be identical to the information sent in response to a `GET` request" [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.4 ], although that _may_ not be actually adhered to, making the proviso necessary, even though it on some level should not be.

Answer (score 60):

For long response bodies (and various other similar situations), the solution I use is always to pipe to `less`, so

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users | less
```

or

```
curl -s -D - https://api.github.com/users | less
```

will do the job.

Comment: these are _not_ equivalent. the first issues a `HEAD` request to which many servers respond differently. the second issues a `GET` request which is more like what we are looking for here.

Comment: This is useful, but not an answer to the question. Therefore, I am voting down.

Answer (score 33):

Maybe it is little bit of an extreme, but I am using this super short version:

```
curl -svo. <URL>
```

Explanation:

`-v` print debug information (which does include headers)

`-o.` send web page data (which we want to ignore) to a certain file, `.` in this case, which is a directory and is an invalid destination and makes the output to be ignored.

`-s` no progress bar, no error information (otherwise you would see `Warning: Failed to create the file .: Is a directory`)

*warning:* result always fails (in terms of error code, if reachable or not). Do not use in, say, conditional statements in shell scripting...

Comment: Why use `-o.` instead of `-o /dev/null`?

Comment: @bfontaine `-o.` is used versus `-o /dev/null` for brevity

Comment: it doesn’t have the same behavior, so it’s strange to use that only to save 8 chars.

Comment: @bfontaine there are other answers that show how to do this the most correct way, this one is here to show the short alternative that does the same thing basically.

Comment: You should clarify in your answer that this command _always_ fails. `curl -svo. <url> && echo foo` won’t print `foo` because `-o.` make `curl` return a non-zero (= error) code: `curl: (23) Failed writing body`.

Comment: a "solution" that ends with returning an error is not a valid solution. it's a happy accident. if something goes wrong, you have no way of knowing because you've already swallowed the error

Comment: @333kenshin it is perfectly fine when you want to quickly use it interactively. Though I do not see how `-vo.` is shorter than `-I` ^^

Answer (score 30):

Much easier – this also follows links.

```
curl -IL http://shortlinktrack.er/in-the-shadows
```

- `-I` is an alias of `--head`, the man page states that it fetch the headers only
- `-L` is an alias of `--location`, the man page states that `curl` will follow the location header if there is one

Answer (score 15):

While the other answers have not worked for me in all situations, the best solution I could find (working with `POST` as well), taken from [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/view-only-headers-with-curl):

`curl -vs 'https://some-site.com' 1> /dev/null`

Comment: I had to put the url between quotes to get this working.

Comment: Whether this is necessary or not might depend on url and used shell. I improved the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

**headcurl.cmd** (windows version)

```
curl -sSkv -o NUL %* 2>&1
```

- I don't want a progress bar `-s`,
- but I do want errors `-S`,
- not bothering about valid https certificates `-k`,
- getting high verbosity `-v` (this is about troubleshooting, is it?),
- no output (in a clean way).
- oh, and I want to [forward **stderr** to **stdout**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420981/444255), so I can grep against the whole thing (since most or all output comes in stderr)
- `%*` means [pass on all parameters to this script] (well(https://stackoverflow.com/a/980372/444255), well usually that's just one parameter: the url you are testing

**real-world example (on troubleshooting proxy issues):**

```
C:\depot>headcurl google.ch | grep -i -e http -e cache
```

```
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
GET HTTP://google.ch/ HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.ch/
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
X-Cache: HIT from company.somewhere.ch
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from company.somewhere.ch:1234
```

---

**Linux version**

for your `.bash_aliases` / `.bash_rc`:

```
alias headcurl='curl -sSkv -o /dev/null $@  2>&1'
```

Comment: This will download the body and consume bandwidth, time. @siracusa 's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679650/6168139) doesn't have this overhead.

Comment: If & when you want POST, add `-X POST` to the passthrough parameters, if you want GET, use GET (i.e. default), as responses may differ. - Unless you do heavy curling in production scripts (not for diagnosis anddevelopment) I don't care about a bit of bandwidth.

Comment: I am planning it to see if files on server are updated or not using 'Last-Modified'. The files in themselves are large, some are in GBs, and I am usually on cellular internet. So, this large bandwidth is an issue for me.

Comment: That would be _hacky_. I don't need to do this as siracusa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679650/6168139) performs the task accurately.

Answer (score 1):

The `-w, --write-out <format>` option can be very helpful. You can get all http headers, or a single one:

```bash
$ curl -s -w '%{header_json}' https://httpbin.org/get -o /dev/null
{"date":["Sun, 18 Feb 2024 13:47:12 GMT"],
"content-type":["application/json"],
"content-length":["254"],
"server":["gunicorn/19.9.0"],
"access-control-allow-origin":["*"],
"access-control-allow-credentials":["true"]
}

$ curl -s -w '%header{content-type}' https://httpbin.org/get -o /dev/null
application/json
```

[read more](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-w)

Answer (score 0):

-D, --dump-header 
Write the protocol headers to the specified file.

```
   This  option  is handy to use when you want to store the headers
   that a HTTP site sends to you. Cookies from  the  headers  could
   then  be  read  in  a  second  curl  invocation by using the -b,
   --cookie option! The -c, --cookie-jar option is however a better
   way to store cookies.
```