# javascript fetch issue of a resource on S3 bucket (delivered by Cloudfront)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch, amazon-cloudfront

I am configuring a simple javascript fetch of a resource on S3 bucket which is delivered by Cloudfront. This is not working not only for localhost but for any other origins, see the response of AWS:

`Response: Access to image at from origin 'http://localhost:3000 ' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

After chatting with AWS support, everything was configurated in the correct way: CORS in S3 bucket, header request in cloudfront distribution, including the following in the "Cache Based on Selected Request Headers" - Headers Whitelist.

- Origin
- Access-control-allow-methods
- Access-control-allow-headers

Cloudfront seems to do not provide Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers.
Have anybody solved the issue of simple fetching from S3 via cloudfront?

```
These are response headers:
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 100286
content-type: image/jpg
date: Mon, 05 Oct 2020 18:36:18 GMT
etag: "81e0932668804433487c4ab834e8a017"
last-modified: Fri, 08 May 2020 01:55:46 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
via: 1.1 4ba9d3779ca8afc198240a34dffb07c4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: 8YQXChq71yTXuTK8OQ4TwtHIYA2oEgqdXvWnUJiU0CHDIxwMiV2iyQ==
x-amz-cf-pop: DUS51-C1
x-amz-version-id: wceb3chundfHz43URYzzrTyIBKh7bisb
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

This is an example of the javascript download code:

````
        const img = new Image();
        // img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';  // This tells the browser to request cross-origin access when trying to download the image data.
        // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Implementing_the_save_feature 

        img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        img.src = image.sampleUrl;
        img.onload = () => {
          // create Canvas
          const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          // create a tag
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.download = 'preview.jpg';
          a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
          a.click();
        };
      };```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6EoF.png

[![cloudfront config][1]][1]
````

Comment: Have you allowed the OPTIONS method? Browsers will usually preflight a CORS request by trying an OPTIONS request and seeing what the server returns. If Cloudfront does not respond to an OPTIONS request it may cause CORS to fail

Comment: Yes I allowed it in CloudFront, but still it is not working

Comment: Have you added the CORS configuration XML to your bucket and specifying the origins that should be allowed?. If not, Check this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

Comment: Yes I did but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing helped, all settings on AWS have been done according to the docs. I finally resolved this using this answer, using as a workaround to add some endings to requested resources:

```
URLs would be something like:

http://.../some.png?http_mysite.com
https://.../some.png?https_mysite.com
```

I took this from this answer:

[Correct S3 + Cloudfront CORS Configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358173/correct-s3-cloudfront-cors-configuration)