# CORS Strict Origin using S3 Bucket and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using a S3 Bucket with a CloudFront distribution on a sub domain but I get strict-origin-when-cross-origin on a GET request. I can't see what I've done wrong so any help is greatly appreciated.
My website url is https://www.project1.tompenn.co.uk/
And my content url is https://content.tompenn.co.uk/TFTSet7_2/traits.json

Developer Console on my website is throwing the error: `Access to fetch at 'https://content.tompenn.co.uk/TFTSet7/traits.json' from origin 'https://www.project1.tompenn.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

[image]

Here is the CORS policy on my S3 Bucket:
[image]

Here is how my CloudFront Distribution is setup. I only have the one behaviour and this is the config for it:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue and after hours of banging my head against the wall I found that something with Chrome's HTTP caching mechanism prevents the `Origin` header from being sent. This is a Chrome-specific issue as I could not reproduce it with Safari. You can check whether this is the case for you as well by toggling the "Disable Cache" option under the [Network tab of Chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucVP.png).

To force your request to ignore the cache, use appropriate `cache` option ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)). This is my final working code:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-store', // for some reason Chrome's caching doesn't send Origin
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay changing this option seems to have solved my issue. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check your cloudfront and S3 configuration based on these links:

- https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/03/21/cors-aws.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/
- [Correct S3 + Cloudfront CORS Configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358173/correct-s3-cloudfront-cors-configuration/63131461#63131461)

Also, as Stephen pointed out, Chrome also has caching that may cause CORS, which can be addressed with:

```
fetch(myRequest, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-store', 
})
```