# append query string while requesting for fonts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Note: This problem is related to firefox being unable to download fonts from cross domain servers

**source: mozilla**
*In Gecko, web fonts are subject to the same domain restriction (font files must be on the same domain as the page using them), unless HTTP access controls are used to relax this restriction. Note: Because there are no defined MIME types for TrueType, OpenType, and WOFF fonts, the MIME type of the file specified is not considered.*

I have a rails application where assets are fetched from amazon cloudfront. CloudFront, in turn, fetches the assets from s3 bucket. I defined the asset_host in production.rb so that assets are fetched from the cloudfront url.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//d582x5cj7qfaa.cloudfront.net"
```

Because I am serving assets from different domain i.e cloudfront. I am unable to download fonts in case of firefox. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229844/amazon-s3-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-and-firefox-cross-domain-font-loa) and applied the same logic as given in the answer, but I was still unable to download the fonts. The reason behind this is, since I have multiple domains (eg: abc.almaconnect.com, xyz.almaconnect.com) that use the same cloudfront url to access fonts, the cloudfront server caches the server headers that were sent in the first request and return the same header even when the domain requesting is different the next time.
Then I came across [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=114646) link, which solves my problem of cache headers i.e if I pass query string along with the url it should work correctly

My question is, how do I append the query_string dynamically through the url? Since the same application is used by multiple domains, I need to real-time method to append query string. How do I do that?

For reference:
Here is the CORS configuration that I used in amazon s3 bucket, which was used by cloudfront url to serve the assets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*.almaconnect.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This is how I came to know what happens with and without appending query_string to the url:

```
 curl -i -H "Origin: https://niet.almaconnect.com" https://d582x5cj7qfaa.cloudfront.net/assets/AlmaConnect-Icons-d059ef02df0837a693877324e7fe1e84.ttf?https_niet.almaconnect.com
```

When will used the same curl request with different origins, without appending the query_string, the returned response contains the origin header that was used in the first request.