# How to allow FontAwesome to load fonts from a different domain

Tags: css, amazon-s3, fonts, font-awesome, amazon-cloudfront

When hosting [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) on a CDN, how do you allow it to load fonts when that CDN's domain does not match your server's domain?

I have my media hosted in an S3 bucket, being served from a Cloudfront endpoint. My webpage, served from `example.com`, contains links to this Cloudfront endpoint, and all the initial media requests to this endpoint succeed. However, if I trigger any JS that tries to render new FontAwesome content, causing it to try and load fonts, I get an error like:

```
Access to Font at 'http://lkfejwifisj.cloudfront.net/font-awesome-4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.d95d6f5d5ab7.woff?v=4.2.0' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I made my S3 bucket's CORS policy as open as possible with the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However, that didn't fix the problem.

I'm using Chrome as my browser, and apparently this type of error has been mentioned [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229844/amazon-s3-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-and-firefox-cross-domain-font-loa) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218237/fontawesome-cross-origin-issues) times before. However, none of the proposed solutions are applicable, or don't work for me.

How do I fix this?

Why is Chrome saying "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource", when I explicitly allow all origins in my CORS configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that my CORSConfiguration is correct, and actually fixes the problem, but my browser is caching the old request and so I still see the same error.

If I load the page in an Incognito browser, ensuring my cache is cleared, I don't get the error.