# AWS S3 CORS error only in Chrome, when using MapBox loadImage function

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, cors, mapbox

I'm using MapBox and I'm looking to add some images to my map that are in an AWS S3 bucket.

The MapBox function that I'm using is [loadImage](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#loadimage). The loadImage docs state that "External domains must support CORS."

My JS code is similar to:

```
this.map.on('load', () => {
    ...
    this.map.loadImage("https://my-test-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/long-uuid-here.png", (error, image) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw error;
    }
// The rest doesn't matter
...
```

When my map loads in chrome I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://my-test-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/long-uuid-here.png' from origin 'https://localhost:7000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

My AWS S3 CORS config is the following:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Using `curl -H "origin: localhost" -v "https://my-test-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/long-uuid-here.png"`, I get the following output:

```
* Connected to my-test-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com (<IP HERE>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Seattle; O=Amazon.com, Inc.; CN=*.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Jul 30 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  4 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my-test-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /default.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-test-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> origin: localhost
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: bLicG+33kfSamR29vMA3BnhmSV27Afooba6yU6hVOPt0mbckO5gefhXN8Ho7hgAEP58s4hKjCf0=
< x-amz-request-id: E760D53EDC5A9804
< Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 22:31:38 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
< Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
< Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 22:37:31 GMT
< ETag: "39eb0bbf2cc33ba02f53f8585004f820"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Content-Length: 16579
< Server: AmazonS3
```

So, it looks like I've got `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header coming back from the AWS S3 server.

I don't receive any CORS error in Firefox.

Is there a problem with my AWS S3 CORS config? Why am I getting these CORS errors in Chrome v86.0.4240.80 (Official Build) (x86_64)?

Note: my bucket isn't actually named "my-test-bucket". I've changed the URL/bucket name for this question. Also, locally I am using `https://localhost` (set it up with a certificate since I need to use the W3C geolocation API which only works over HTTPS), if it matters

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this is a caching issue with Chrome. I found an answer on this question: [CORS problems with Amazon S3 on the latest Chomium and Google Canary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253472/cors-problems-with-amazon-s3-on-the-latest-chomium-and-google-canary), from @nassan that suggests adding `?cacheblock=true` as a query parameter to the GET request.

So, changing my code to:

```
this.map.loadImage(`${dealInfo.properties.logo}?cacheblock=true`, (error, image) => {
    ...
})
```

Resolves the CORS errors that occur in Chrome.

Looks like this is the issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090.

I also added `crossorigin="anonymous"` to my script tag.

Seems like this being a Chrome caching issue (header caching?) also explains why I could see the expected headers using `curl`, but Chrome complained that they weren't there.

Comment: I'm with the Chrome guys here - their caching behaviour is perfectly legal, and it is actually S3 at fault for not returning a Vary header on non-CORS requests. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=342401 where I've tried to summarise it.

Comment: It does seem to be an AWS S3 is at-fault on this. However, they have been aware of it for some time, it seems, and it hasn't been fixed. So, the workaround seems to be in order for now.