# jwplayer crossdomain issue - IE9 only

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

trying to play a movie on IE9 (jwplayer 6) - getting Error loading skin: Crossdomain loading denied.

my skin (and player buttons) are on the same domain as my page.

There is no error on other browsers, only on IE9.

what can i do?

Comment: where are u running it ?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

As per the assumption based on the information provided in the question, I am suggesting two solution with two common scenarios which might have caused this issue.

1. If you are using CDN for video, jwplayer files and skins then then You need to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in your CDN server. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395148/1877909))
2. You should include `crossdomain.xml` in your server as per the instructions in [jwplayersite](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062550-crossdomain-loading-denied). ([See here also](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403679-crossdomain-file-loading))

I hope above two solution works.