# Why I add a ServerAlias failed?

Tags: wordpress, apache

I use apache, my website has a ServerName 'yueai', I want to add a ServerAlias '192.168.1.154'.  But it didn't work on some broswers, and on chrome it show the following error:

```
Font from origin 'http://yueai' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource 
Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://192.168.1.154' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the ServerAlias, you are running into a CORS issue: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577981/font-from-origin-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing