# "Access to Font..has been blocked by CORS policy" on only one file

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

> Note: I am using Wordpress and serving the media files, css, js, etc. through Amazon CloudFront/S3.

Hello,

I know there are a lot of posts like this but I am still struggling. I was able to fix this issue for a majority of the font files that I am loading, however, this one continues to be an issue.

```
Access to Font at 'http://mycloudfrontID.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/bridge/css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3' from origin 'http://mydomainname' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://maxmajor.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The other font files are fine after I added this to my CORS policy on AWS S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and this is in my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas why this error is still firing?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

with this:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Also I read 
[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765)

[Font from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577981/font-from-origin-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing)

that for security reasons you have to include your URL.

So, your .htaccess should have this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mysitename.com"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Works for me!

Comment: Highly appreciated. I have used htaccess solution in my project. Thanks dear, You saved my life :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered referring the following thread?
[CORS Issue with woff2 fonts behind CDN in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893199/cors-issue-with-woff2-fonts-behind-cdn-in-chrome)

It says

> Turns out that the problem was actually with the **Content-Type**. As soon as I **changed the content type to application/font-woff2** and invalidated the cache of these woff2 files, everything went through smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are sending `Authorization` headers with your `GET` requests for the fonts?

If not, in your S3 CORS policy change

`<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>`

to

`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`.

This tiny miss had bugged me for a month.