# WEB.DEV - Access to font at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: cors, policy

i get this errors not on my website but when i test it on web.dev in section "Best Practices" ... how can i fix that ?

Some here says this code will fix it :

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)$">
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I put the code above in my .htaccess but google still gives that error

Answer (score 0):

Based on [shaitana & Stephen Ostermiller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236969/11127990)'s answer you could add this rule to your `.htaccess`

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Or better if you specified the domain value

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your-domain.example"
```