# What header settings do I need to use with Cloudfront so that the bootstrap glyphicons render in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have Cloudfront setup as my cdn (first time I have tried using it). The site renders perfectly without Cloudfront but with it the glyphicons disappear. To see what I mean look [here](http://www.meadowrecording.com/). The square boxes are supposed to be arrows.

I read in another SO post that I need to set my cors headers in Cloudfront but I cannot find any information on what the specifics of doing this are (I have already installed and setup rack-cors gem). Currently the cdn 'Forward headers' are set to none. Which one/s do I need to turn on to get the glyphicons to render or is their another solution to this?

Comment: Did u see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229844/amazon-s3-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-and-firefox-cross-domain-font-loa. There are detailed and accepted answers for the same question as yours.

Comment: I missed that one somehow. Thanks