# Fonts are not loaded first time page load

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, fonts, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When my website first time loaded the fonts are not loaded. I'm receiving following errors

```
Font from origin 'https://locohop.com' has been blocked from loading by 
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://locohop.com'
is therefore not allowed access.
```

I lots off googling and this question is already asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229844/amazon-s3-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-and-firefox-cross-domain-font-loa)

I follow all the steps given in above question but fonts are not worked correctly. and
I am using AWS EC2 instance

Here is my CORS configuration

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://www.locohop.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://www.locohop.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I don't know why i am getting this error? your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly you don't mention whether you've read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html or not, so: what happens when you use that page's simplest example? (just the allowedOrigin and allowedMethod, with a `*` header allowance)

Comment: @Mike Yes! I've read [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) and also checked AllowedHeader * but font doesn't  worked

Comment: The browser says no CORS header is being sent: are you sure you made your CORS configuration take effect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CORS policy in your .htacess

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "locohop.com"
```