# Looking for Jboss version of a web URL

Tags: linux, curl, jboss, fingerprinting

I have a web URL and I wanted to check on which JBOSS version it is running. May I know how can I do that? It is possible to check using `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060098/getting-only-response-header-from-http-post-using-curl) link has some good examples but a simple attempt would be the following:

```
$ curl -I 10.128.36.43:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"1477-1320989163000"
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Nov 2011 05:26:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1477
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 13:27:23 GMT
```

-I, --head is:
(HTTP  FTP  FILE) Fetch the headers only! HTTP-servers feature the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header of a
              document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the file size and last modification time only.

Comment: Did this answer help Law?

Comment: @Law, did this help?