# How to get rsync command on windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, deployment, rsync

I am using flightplan with to deploy my node.js application in production. 
Here is my flightplan.js file.

```
var plan = require('flightplan');

plan.target('default', {
    host: {{host}},
    username: {{ username }},
    port: '2222',
    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK
});

plan.local(function(local) {
    local.log('Copy files to remote hosts');
    var filesToCopy = local.exec('git ls-files', { silent: true });
    // rsync files to all the destination's hosts
    local.transfer(filesToCopy, '~/www/');
});
```

When I run fly default it stops and says

> 'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command

How can I get rsync command? I am running windows 8.

Comment: Rsync is for Linux-based OS only.. There is no Rsync command in Windows

Answer (score 14):

You can install free version of cwRsync :

https://www.itefix.net/content/cwrsync-free-edition

Unzip all files to c:\rsync for example, then add c:\rsync to your path.

Here is a tutorial to add a folder in your path on Windows : http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Comment: You can also write a windows 1-line `rsync.bat` “stub” (a command that [purely fowards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/980372/444255) to that rsync folder with the .exe and accompaigning dll's) like so: `C:\depot\script\rsync\rsync.exe %*`. — as long as that .bat is placed somewhere in the path, you are done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using WSL or [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) on Windows. cwRsync is part of Cygwin, which requires strange paths to work.